# What is the task size in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

In the App Engine's push queues, the task size limit is given as 100KB.

So, task size in this case is

1. Memory limit for entire task processing?(or)
2. Memory limit of Input to the task?

I have a large spreadsheet (of log files), and I need to do some processing on them. So, I'm thinking to process some fixed number of rows as a single task each time while passing a global counter (last # row processed) to the task.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. Think of this limit in terms of physical storage. You are allowed to store 100KB of data in the tasks context.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the 'task' as a detailed instruction for a worker. The size of the instruction (which is essentially an encoded URL to be delivered to an endpoint in your app) is limited to 100K. This restriction doesn't speak to the resources the worker might user to perform the instruction. That's covered by a separate set of restrictions.